# LATEX: Creating a loop graph from adjacency matrix 1

Tags: matrix, graph, latex, adjacency-matrix

I do not know how to draw the graph of this adjacency matrix using latex.
this is the matrix

```
  1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  1  1  1  0  1
  0  0  1  1  0  0
  1  1  0  1  0  1
  0  1  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  1  1  1
```

The edges should be labeled as A, B, C, D, E, F. The graph is a mixed graph with loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/), and so you can draw whatever you want with it. Many examples are online, you can for example see the question with [self-loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45806/tikzpicture-how-can-i-draw-a-loop-right-below)